# Mail.app doesn't use my default browser for authenticating accounts

Tags: macos, mail.app, firefox

If I log into Gmail from Mail.app, it wants to authenticate from a browser, so Mail.app obliges. However, my default browser is Firefox (currently 92.0), but Mail opens Safari.

How can I change that?

I'm running Big Sur (11.5.2) and Mail.app Version 14.0 (3654.120.0.1.13)

Answer (score 2):

The authentication is part of the system, so it requires a response from wether the authentication was successful which any regular Browser could not give (as it is lacking the interface that Mail and this (Safari-like) Web View will use to pass back the information to each other).

td:dr - You can't.

Comment: On bigsur when Chrome is default browser I experience that the system tries to get chrome to open the oauth flow browser window and forces chrome into focus (can't get back to the mail or internet accounts window without quitting chrome) but chrome never pops the auth window.

Changing default browser back to safari resolves the login issue but then I'm stuck with safari as default browser.  So it is possible somehow...but the experience is broken.  Pretty terrible user experience.  This is clean install Big Sur as well...so not sure how I got it into this state.